# How do I iterate through a queue?

Tags: python, queue

I have this code which will search for the leaf nodes in a tree using BFS

```
import queue

def BFS(lst,que):

    jst=[]

    for x in range(len(lst)):
        if 2*x+1<=len(lst)-1 and 2*x+2<=len(lst)-1:
            que.put(lst[2*x+1])
            que.put(lst[2*x+2])

    for y in iter(que.get(),None):
        if y in lst:
            if 2*(lst.index(y))<=len(lst)-1 and 2*(lst.index(y))+2<=len(lst)-1:
                que.get()
    return y



lst=[]
y=[]

x=int(input('Enter how many nodes:'))
if x%2==0:
    print("not the correct no of nodes")
else:
    for i in range(x):
        lst.append((input("Enter the nodes: ")))
    que=queue.Queue(maxsize=10)
    y.append(BFS(lst,que))
print(y)
```

It shows me an error: `TypeError: iter(v, w): v must be callable`, whereas I saw in some other post that this method works. Is there any other way to iterate through the queue?

Comment: `que.get()` gets an element from the queue, so `iter(que.get(), None)` is trying to iterate over a single element. One element isn't iterable. Try `iter(que.get, None)`.

Comment: Generally you *don't* iterate over a queue; you take whatever element is at the head of the queue. Also, why use BFS to find the leaves? DFS is much simpler.

Comment: *I saw in some other post that this method works*. A link to that post could be helpful in understanding your thinking.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay even if you don't use `iter()`. The function `queue.get()` does the job of getting out the next element from the queue. Hence your code may work without using `iter()`.

```
import queue

def BFS(lst,que):

    jst=[]

    for x in range(len(lst)):
        if 2*x+1<=len(lst)-1 and 2*x+2<=len(lst)-1:
            que.put(lst[2*x+1])
            que.put(lst[2*x+2])

    for y in que.get():
        if y in lst:
            if 2*(lst.index(y))<=len(lst)-1 and 2*(lst.index(y))+2<=len(lst)-1:
                que.get()
    return y


lst=[]
y=[]

x=int(input('Enter how many nodes:'))
if x%2==0:
    print("not the correct no of nodes")
else:
    for i in range(x):
        lst.append((input("Enter the nodes: ")))
    que=queue.Queue(maxsize=10)
    # also do not this change!
    y = y.append(BFS(lst,que))
print(y)
```